# How to inject services into instances of classes (that not services) in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have the next solution, but what is the best practice for angular2?

```
...

class MultitonObject {
    _http: Http;

    constructor (appInjector: Injector) {
        this._http = appInjector.get(Http);
    }
}

var app = bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ...]);

app.then(componentRef => {
  var new_instance = new MultitonObject(componentRef.injector);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't or don't want to make `MultitonObject` a service?

Comment: I don't even understand exactly what you're trying to achive?

Comment: My example based on Angular2 tutorial.
Imagine, we want to create Heroes in different parts of application. Sometimes we want to save this heroes using injected Http into Hero instance.

var hero = new Hero(name="Windstorm");
hero.setName("Windstorm 2");
hero.save();

Comment: @VictorK: Have you found a solution ?  I am having a similar design pattern, based on this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/17/angular-2-series-part-2-domain-models-and-dependency-injection/)

Comment: There are two ways of doing this. The first one, I explained above. The second is using global variables, but in this case you will not be able to use several instances of your application. Therefore, I choose the first.
Of course, if you then need to create your class instances within services or components, you can inject Injector in a general way and then use it in your class constructor. I'm not an expert, but I think that the tutorial's aproach is like mine yet a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Angulars dependency injection can only inject to classes it creates itself. If you create an instance yourself with `new MyClass()` there is nothing Angular can do about.

The code in your question is fine for this use case.